# External displays keep getting back in the wrong order

Tags: macos, display

I work with my macbook (16", 10.15.7) closed and plugged into two external monitors, with two [Apple USB-C Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter).

One adapter has HDMI, Power and USB-A plugged, and is connected to my main display (the one that should be on the left on the image below.)

The other adapter has only HDMI plugged and is connected to my secondary display (the one that should be on the right on the image below.)

And almost every single time I plug the adapters, the displays are set in the wrong order (left and right are swapped) and I have to go to `System Preferences > Displays` to organize them correctly again.

Even If I unplug the one that should be on the right, wait and plug it again, macOS keep setting it on the left.

[I successfully reset the NVRAM/PRAM but it does not resolve this behavior.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342569)

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem?

[image: Display issue]

Comment: Are the displays identical? This can also happen if they are just vaguely similar. Sometimes it's easier to give up the fight & swap the physical order. I had to do this on 2 almost identical Dells 5 or 6 years ago. Once it's decided which way it prefers them, let it win;)

Comment: Hey @Tetsujin, nice idea! Yes they are identical. I tried, it seems to be less buggy but it is still happening. I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using 2 monitors of the same model, where one is pivoted for quite some time (where it's even more obvious immediately when plugging in).

The solution in my case: Plug out both adapters and plug them in in the other order. In my case I had to plug in the main monitor (in terms of the one which holds the menu bar) first.

Answer (score 0):

<s>OMG i think i fixed it</s> not fixed, leaving notes for the next person or my next attempt

**Problem**: in a complex multi-display arrangement, display arrangement is shuffled or lost on awake from sleep, shuffling windows around which need to be dragged back onto the correct monitor and position.

**Root cause**: when you use N identical displays, MacOS can't (or doesn't) distinguish them, so MacOS assigns `persistent screen id` based on order of connection; a race condition. This happens every time the displays connect, i.e. when the computer awakes from sleep.

**Specs**:

- MacOS Ventura, 2022 Mac Studio M1 Ultra
- 3x matching monitors 2560@144hz + 1x 4k@60hz scaled to 3360
- arrangement - modified tie fighter

**Solution**:

- Install https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer
- use `displayplacer list` to dump your current configuration
- At the bottom (Line 971 for me), it says:

> Execute the command below to set your screens to the current arrangement. If screen ids are switching, please run `displayplacer --help` for info on using contextual or serial ids instead of persistent ids.
>
> `displayplacer "id:8408D084-471C-4059-A18F-A4B161D2D378 res:2560x1440 hz:144 color_depth:7 enabled:true scaling:off origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:2B4FB452-0D2F-411D-B8CC-F0C78F860732 res:2560x1440 hz:144 color_depth:7 enabled:true scaling:off origin:(0,-1440) degree:180" "id:D1C1F2C0-44ED-473D-92FC-B0B18FC1D54E res:3360x1890 hz:60 color_depth:8 enabled:true scaling:on origin:(-3360,-327) degree:0" "id:D7845BCD-3AB9-4AD9-BE66-EFDA2E6FD81C res:1440x2560 hz:144 color_depth:7 enabled:true scaling:off origin:(2560,-552) degree:270"`

- Edit the command to address displays not by persistent screen id, but some other stable and unique ID (serial screen ID is unique for me)
- run the command

**Test**:

- Sleep and unsleep, observe windows stay in the same place!

**References**

https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer#screenids-switching

> Unfortunately, macOS sometimes changes the persistent screenIds when there are race conditions from external screens waking up in non-determinisic order. If none of the screenId options below work for your setup, please search around in the GitHub Issues for conversation regarding this. Many people have written shell scripts to work around this issue. Recommended discussions are one, two, three, four, five, six.
>
> You can mix and match screenId types across your setup.
>
> Persistent screenIds usually stay the same. They are recommended for most use cases.
> Contextual screenIds change when switching GPUs or when cables switch ports. > If you notice persistent screenIds switching around, try using the contextual screenIds.
> Serial screenIds are tied to your display hardware. If the serial screenIds are unique for all of your monitors, use these.

See also https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer/pull/96#issuecomment-1416714458

Comment: Is this an answer to actually *solve or address the problem* or just an explanation?